# Using Year(Date) in IF statement but no output

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to grab data from three columns in my workbook `AK`,`AL` and AM respectively. After getting the data I am doing 3 different comparisons which are stated in the code below.

Firstly, I am comparing the date in Column `AL` and Column `AM`. I am checking if Column `AL` is of year 2018 and Column `AM` is not of year 2018. If its true then It will insert text in Column `L` called "Routine". This is done cell by cell using a for loop as seen in the code.

Next, there is a check if Column `AM` is of year 2018 and Column `AK` is color coded to *Yellow* color. If it is true then text will be inserted in Column `L` called "New".

Lastly, there is a check if Column `AM` is of year 2018 and Column `AK` is not colored in *Yellow*. If it is true then text will be inserted in Column 'L' called "Major"

Else, The cell will be left blank without any data inserted.

PROBLEM: The code runs fine and there are no issues or errors. But I am not able to get the output I want. The code does not insert any text in the Column `L`

```
Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wb As Worksheet
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date

Set wbk = Application.Workbooks("MaxiTrak RV Service Report - Blank.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wbk.Worksheets("ML_PSV_SERVICE")

lastrow = ws1.range("AL" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To lastrow

    date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 38).Value
    date2 = ws1.Cells(j, 39).Value

        If Year(date1) = Year(Date) - 1 And Year(date2) <> Year(Date) - 1 Then
            Cells(j, 12).Value = "Routine"
            If Year(date2) = Year(Date) - 1 And Cells(j, 37).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                Cells(j, 12).Value = "New"
                If Year(date2) = Year(Date) - 1 And Cells(j, 37).Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then
                    Cells(j, 12).Value = "Major"
                Else
                    Cells(j, 12).Value = ""
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
```

[Sample Output expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvhOo.png)

Comment: You're doing way too many date checks.  Based on the code, you only need to test `Year(date1) = Year(Date) - 1 And Year(date2) <>  Year(date1)`, and only test that *once*.

Comment: Show some source and expected results - perhaps the correct output is 0...

Comment: @SolarMike I have added a sample output picture under the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code below, it's pretty simple and self-explanatory:

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Year(Range("AM" & i)) <> 2018 Then
            If Year(Range("AL" & i)) = 2018 Then Range("L" & i) = "Routine"
        ' column AM has year equal to 2018
        ElseIf Range("AK" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            Range("L" & i) = "New"
        Else
            Range("L" & i) = "Major"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code that you supplied you have:

```
            If Year(date2) = Year(Date) - 1 And Cells(j, 37).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                Cells(j, 12).Value = "New"
                If Year(date2) = Year(Date) - 1 And Cells(j, 37).Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then
                    Cells(j, 12).Value = "Major"
                Else
                    Cells(j, 12).Value = ""
                End If
            End If
```

Where you get into the first if statement because `cells(j,37).interior.colorindex = 6`, but then, you do a check where `cells(j,37).interior.colorindex <> 6`.

The conflict here is that it will always set `cells(j,12).value = ""`.  Either your first cell reference is off or your second reference is off. Another possibility is that you need to change one of the `colorindex` values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added a sample output that I require under my question. If that could clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I believe you have too many if statements. You also have an if statement nested inside another if statement.

```
Dim j, lastrow As Long
Dim ws1, wb As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim dateAL, dateAM As Date
Dim colorID As Variant

Set wbk = Application.Workbooks("MaxiTrak RV Service Report - Blank.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wbk.Worksheets("ML_PSV_SERVICE")

lastrow = ws1.Range("AL" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
currentyear = Year(Date)

For j = 2 To lastrow

    dateAL = Year(ws1.Cells(j, 38).Value) ' column AL
    dateAM = Year(ws1.Cells(j, 39).Value) ' column AM
    colorID = ws1.Cells(j, 37).Interior.ColorIndex

    If dateAL = currentyear - 1 And dateAM <> currentyear - 1 Then
        Cells(j, 12).Value = "Routine"
    Else
        If dateAM = currentyear - 1 And colorID = 6 Then
            Cells(j, 12).Value = "New"
        Else
            Cells(j, 12).Value = "Major"
        End If
    End If

Next j
```

Try the above code, but please review the code FIRST.

Comment: Thank you! @IrwinAllen13 The code run without any errors when I press the CommandButton1 from my excel sheet but it will not bring any data in Column 'L' . So, I tried to execute that particular function line by line using the debugger and it works well but, it doesn't output data to cells on clicking Commandbutton1.